# Labeling grid automatically using QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling

I have a polygon layer with a number as label. Now I want that my labeling is always in the left upper corner of the single polygon, like in the screenshot.The red rectangle is the position, where the label should be placed

[image]

If I zoom in the should be visible and placed like in the second screenshot.

[image]

If such a labeling is possible, how can I create that?

I tried the labeling tab of the gui, but it doesn´t work pretty well
With my settings the labels of other polygons where placed in their visible neighbours

[image]

Comment: Not exactly the same, but I had a similar question: [Extract coordinates of lower right corners of polygon](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/261519/extract-coordinates-of-lower-right-corners-of-polygon). The expression can be used to control the labeling, too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**To get that result in QGIS 3.14:**

- Check the 'Geometry generator' option inside the labels options and add `make_point(x_min( $geometry), y_max( $geometry))` in the expression box
- Select 'Offset from point' placement
- Select the bottom right Placement Quadrant
- Adjust the 'Offset X,Y' settings to move the label a little away from the corner if necessary

[image]

**An alternative method for older QGIS versions:**

- Duplicate your layer (we'll use one layer for the grid and another for the labels)
- Select 'Single Symbol' styling
- Select 'Geometry Generator' as 'Symbol layer type'
- Select 'Point/Multipoint' as 'Geometry type'
- Add `make_point(x_min( $geometry), y_max( $geometry))` in the expression box
- Change the  'Symbol layer type' under 'Geometry Generator' from 'Simple marker' to 'Font marker'.
- Set the 'Anchor point' to 'top left'
- Click on the 'Data defined overide' button next to the 'Character' box and select 'Edit'.
- In the window that pops up type in the field name (between double quotes) you want to use to label.
- Click OK
- Adjust the 'Offset X,Y' settings to move the label a little away from the corner if necessary

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Then we have to update our QGIS version in the company. Now we use QGIS 3.4.8 LTR. In this version I don´t find the geometry generator in the placement tab

Comment: I've added an alternative for older QGIS versions, that even works in QGIS 2.18.

Answer (score 4):

To completely answer the question we need to extend the answer of Michel by adding a label to any grid squares cut off by the top and left hand edges of the canvas. This can be done by updating the geometry expression to:

```
make_point(x_min(intersection(@map_extent, $geometry)), y_max( intersection(@map_extent, $geometry)))
```

[image]

Comment: Could I force the labeling into the associated polygon? If I zoom in, some labels of cut off polygons appear in other polygons.